# Filter by predicate attributes

Tags: sparql, wikidata

How can I get all chairpersons, which are still holding this job (where the predicate has no end date?).

My current version returns all chairpersons:

```
SELECT ?chairperson ?x WHERE {
  ?university wdt:P488 ?chairperson.
}
```

Comment: `SELECT ?university ?chairperson WHERE {
  ?university p:P488 ?stmt.
  ?stmt ps:P488 ?chairperson 
  filter not exists {?stmt pq:P582 ?end}
}` - you should also add some type triple pattern for universities I guess

Comment: Thanks @AKSW, that was exactly what I was looking for. That was only a (minimal) example, in the original version there are already type triple ;)

Comment: @AKSW seems you should convert your comment to an answer